# Can't parse json object(android)

Tags: android, json

Sorry for my English, I can't parse `json` object like this:

```
{
    "user": {
        "id": 34,
        "last_login": {
            "date": "2015-07-30 11:22:34.000000",
            "timezone_type": 3,
            "timezone": "Europe/Oslo"
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know, why it's not working. I need parse `last_login`, but I can't do this

**My code**

```
JSONObject jsonTable = json.getJSONObject("user");

                if(jsonTable.length() > 0) {
                    check = true;

                    ProfileDetalisObject pfDet = new ProfileDetalisObject();

                    pfDet.setId(jsonTable.getString(TAG_ID));


                    JSONObject date = jsonTable.getJSONObject("last_login");
                    if(date.length() > 0) {
                        Iterator<String> iteratorDate = date.keys();

                        while( iteratorDate.hasNext() ) {
                            String currentKeySensor = iteratorDate.next();
                            JSONObject objDate = date.optJSONObject(currentKeySensor);

                            if(objDate != null) {
                                pfDet.setDate(objDate.getString("date"));
                                pfDet.setTimezone_type(objDate.getString("timezone_type"));
                                pfDet.setTimezone(objDate.getString("timezone"));
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

I can't parse `last_login`.

Comment: Use gson: https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`last_login` is normal json object (aka dictionary), so you do not need any iterators, just reach the keys directly:

```
JSONObject date = jsonTable.getJSONObject("last_login");
pfDet.setDate(date.getString("date"));
pfDet.setTimezone_type(date.getString("timezone_type"));
pfDet.setTimezone(date.getString("timezone"));
```